# programmatically create Background Images in Flex 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, visualization

I'm developing a visualization for certain parts of a Warehouse with Flex 3. In this visualization there are lot of blocks where 1 to x pallets can be placed where x is between 9 and 15. I need to represent each pallet with a black square, each place which is already assigned to a pallet but not physically taken with a grey square and each free place with a white square. I first thought to just use a canvas for each place on a block and change their color if the state changes. But the hundreds of canvases which are there as a result of this approach are not updated quickly enough for my purposes (screen freezes for a few seconds).

I don't want to use embedded images because of the great amount of images I had to embed in the application (those Images appear in 4 orientations).

My idea was to create background images which reflect the state of the whole block only when needed for that certain state and cache them, so that the computation time is spread over the whole runtime.

My problem now is I don't know how to create them in a way that I can use them as "backgroundImages". As far as I understand I would need them as a class object but I don't know how to achieve that, when not embedding the images.

I'm of course open to better approaches to solve my problem. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [Graphics](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html) property of a Sprite for example. It provides basic drawing API, like drawing lines, circles and rectangles.

Besides, you can draw bitmap images on the Graphics to produce more advances results.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was so focused on my idea of caching that I didn't consider implementing this as own class and do it for every block. I will try it and give you feedback if it works :)